# Is it possible for public users to run experiments using Qiskit's surface code?

Tags: qiskit, error-correction, surface-code

I'm an undergrad who would like to run some experiments using the surface code. I've been able to use their quantum repetition code (https://qiskit.org/textbook/ch-quantum-hardware/error-correction-repetition-code.html) but how do I access the surface code?

If its not possible, are there any other open source software besides qiskit that allow users to run their surface codes?

Comment: IBM's chips don't have the connectivity required by the surface code, so it's reasonably complicated to compile it into a circuit that would actually run. I'd be surprised if you found any working end-to-end code for it, instead of having to write your own.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use qtcodes Python library which is using qiskit. It is still a baby library, but this is the only thing I found. I am actually planning to override it and expand it.